# writing a special character in sed bash

Tags: linux, bash, sed, command, display

I have a problem, because I want to replace

```
QueryConnection::DefaultChannel=
```

with

```
QueryConnection::DefaultChannel=/${CHANNEL NUMBER}
```

e.g:
QueryConnection::DefaultChannel=/5

My code:

```
sed -i "s/QueryConnection::DefaultChannel=.*/QueryConnection::DefaultChannel=${NUMER_KANALU}/" "${DIR_BOTS}/bot_${COUNT_BOTS}/configTS3AudioBot.cfg"
```

How to make before ${NUMER_KANALU} be "/"?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Escape a string for a sed replace pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/407523/608639), [What characters do I need to escape when using sed in a sh script?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/32907/56041), etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two choices:

1. Escape the slash:

   ```
   sed -i "s/QueryConnection::DefaultChannel=.*/QueryConnection::DefaultChannel=\/${NUMER_KANALU}/" "${DIR_BOTS}/bot_${COUNT_BOTS}/configTS3AudioBot.cfg"
   ```
2. Use a different delimiter around the `s` parameters:

   ```
   sed -i "s#QueryConnection::DefaultChannel=.*#QueryConnection::DefaultChannel=/${NUMER_KANALU}#" "${DIR_BOTS}/bot_${COUNT_BOTS}/configTS3AudioBot.cfg"
   ```